# How to add Typescript support for Leaflet Plugin

Tags: typescript, plugins, leaflet

I need to add TS support for this Leaflet Plugin: https://github.com/yakitoritabetai/Leaflet.LabelTextCollision

Does anyone know how I can do that? I was trying to create a .d.ts file, but because this plugin exposes the whole extension of the Canvas class and everything that inside the plugin is hidden in the block scope, I don't understand how can I declare types for all methods and arguments inside?

```
L.LabelTextCollision = L.Canvas
    .extend({ ... });
```

Maybe someone can give an advice where should I start if my goal is to cover the whole plugin with TS support?
Thanks!

I was trying to look into TS docs, but Plugins seem to be quite a specific thing.

Comment: Go to the leafletjs website in the plugins section and search for a plugin that is built with typescript and you can rebuild the plugin based on it.

Comment: @GrzegorzT, how could I know that it is built with TS, and where I can get .d.ts file -  https://github.com/yakitoritabetai/Leaflet.LabelTextCollision - I can find this plugin in Plugins section in Leaflet docs but I don't know if it was compiled from TS